# JS, второй уровень вложенности массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Здравствуйте. У меня затуп :)

Есть массив:

```
{
    id: 1,
    questions: "Сколько у вас места?",
    options: [
        {
            userPick: "Много",
            moveTo: 2
        },
        {
            userPick: "Немного есть",
            moveTo: 3
        },
        {
            userPick: "могу выделить угол в комнате",
            moveTo: 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Мн нужно добраться к userPick. Надо бы forEach-ем, но не пойму как

Comment: Есть объект, а не массив.

Comment: @Qwertiy, но это все равно просто структура данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {
    id: 1,
    questions: "Сколько у вас места?",
    options: [
        {
            userPick: "Много",
            moveTo: 2
        },
        {
            userPick: "Немного есть",
            moveTo: 3
        },
        {
            userPick: "могу выделить угол в комнате",
            moveTo: 4
        }
    ]
}

for (var q=0; q<data.options.length; ++q) {
  console.log(data.options[q].userPick)
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @Біпач, если этот ответ решил твою проблему, его надо принять нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Я не могу принять ответ через 8 минут :)

Comment: @Біпач, ой :) Быстро я ответил)))

Answer (score 1):

```
  var data = {
    id: 1,
    questions: "Сколько у вас места?",
    options: [
      {
        userPick: "Много",
        moveTo: 2
      },
      {
        userPick: "Немного есть",
        moveTo: 3
      },
      {
        userPick: "могу выделить угол в комнате",
        moveTo: 4
      }
    ]
  };

 data.options.map((u) => console.log(u.userPick));
```